# What is structural RNA?

Tags: bioinformatics, genomics

In genbank (ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/archive/old_refseq/Fungi/Saccharomyces_cerevisiae_uid128/) there are an archive *.frn* (nucleotide sequences of structural RNAs in fasta format), and  I want to know the differences between structural RNAs and genes. 
Are the nucleotide sequences of structural RNAs a coding region?

My goal is separate the coding region from the non coding region of a given complete genome.

I'm physicist so, I apologize if my question is pretty simple.

Comment: @David I guess "structural RNA" is not a standard term. I won't even expect biologists to be sure about what it could mean.

Comment: @WYSIWYG — Inspection of one file with extension .fm gives names for some of these structural RNAs, such as Pro tRNA, 15S ribosomal RNA. I assume the poster has read this. I would have expected him to try to find out what a tRNA and a ribosomal RNA actually was. If he is not prepared to put the effort into reading about molecular biology he is wasting his (and our) time.

Answer (score 4):

To be very brief: A gene is a sequence of DNA or RNA, which is hereditary and has a biological function. In the *Saccharomyces cerevisiae* genome you posted, every gene is a DNA sequence. The function of most genes is to be [transcribed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcription_(biology))  to messenger RNA (mRNA), which is then [translated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_(biology)) to a protein. "Coding" DNA refers to DNA which eventually has its sequence translated into protein

Structural RNAs are encoded by genes but not translated to protein, and thus *are not* coding regions. They are made up of RNA, but function more like proteins. When they enable reactions, like enzymes, they are called [Ribozymes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribozyme). The most well known ones are the [Ribosomes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribosome), which are an essential part of protein biosynthesis. Others form special structures which help molecules recognize each other. [tRNAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_RNA) are needed for the ribosome to recognize the right amino acids.

As David said, this is very basic molecular biology and gene regulation/expression in eukaryotes can get [quite complex](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK9904/). The wikipedia articles provide a good introduction and the Berg biochemistry book he linked is excellent further reading. If you want to know more about yeast genomes, you can check out https://www.yeastgenome.org/. It provides a whole lot of information regarding the amount of coding/noncoding regions and their function. There is also a graphical genome browser, where you can view each region in detail and compare it with your own findings.

Comment: Coding DNA refers specifically to regions that are translated into protein. Non-coding RNA like tRNA or rRNA are by definition not part of coding regions.

Comment: i approved the edit but i am not sure if it is okay to change key concept of another user's answer.

Comment: molecular biology terminologies tend to be tricky and sometimes usage vary from person to person.